# Is it possible to use your keyboard's function keys in Android Studio Emulator?

Tags: android-emulator

I have to create an Android application for a device that will have an external keyboard. This external keyboard makes it possible to type characters with the help of ALT GR and use function keys.

The Emulator of Android Studio currently does not support this. Not all keys are recognized and the soft keyboard doesn't contain function keys. This makes developing and testing rather hard in my particular case.

Is there any way to let Android Studio Emulator recognize these keys on my keyboard or remap certain keys (current ALT GR behavior of the emulator is unwanted)?